# Openlayers2: how i can draw path with more than 2 points

Tags: path, openlayers

My problem is what i can draw `itinerary` between multi-points in `openlayers 2`.i have more than 2 points.

how i can draw the path of car in map with openlayers2.

Comment: Take a pen and just draw a path on your screen?

Comment: it's not simple like this i like draw it automatically with openlayers api !!!